# How can I improve video performance with Radeon R7 370

Tags: drivers, 16.04, video, radeon, framerate

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a (Dell) machine with a Radeon R7 370 video card. Now videos, including those stored locally, when played seem to have a very low Frame Per Second value. You can almost see each frame repainting from top to bottom. The result is virtually unwatchable. Also, no GLX applications will run.

I know the proprietary AMD drivers were discontinued for 16.04 and we are (hopefully) using the Open Source amdgpl driver, although I cannot confirm that this is what my system is actually using. I have installed mesa-utils and other mesa packages I have seen referenced in other posts, but nothing seems to help.

I had terrible luck with 2 previous NVidia cards under 14.04 and purchased the Radeon after searching Ubuntu's site for compatible cards. This one is listed as compatible. The site appears to be a little behind with regards 16.04 and I am running out of places to look.

I am even willing to purchase a forth video card if someone can tell me one that will provide full GLX and other functionality as well as good graphics and video performance.

Comment: Integrated Intel graphics have great video performance aside from heavy gaming. But to check if your system is using the radeon,do `dmesg | grep radeon` to see if the radeon driver is being used. If you get nothing from that, then you're not using radeon drivers.